# How to find files that contain parenthesis using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, text, filenames

I have a google script that outputs a text file of a list of songs (Artist / Title).

I have a folder of mp3's.

I have the following script that will use the text file to search the mp3 folder and move mp3's from the list to a new folder.

```
 CHCP 65001 > NUL

 FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%I IN ("G:\My Drive\PopStream.txt") DO (
 xcopy /s "H:\RECORDED\The POP Stream\%%I" "H:\PREBROADCAST\The POP Stream\%%I*" 

 )
```

This works... almost.

The problem that I have is:
If a song title has parenthesis "( )" it won't find and move the file.

EXAMPLE:
"Sports Team - Happy (God's Own Country)"

The search will find no results. How can I make the search find these items?

Comment: Well, there no code that is searching any files since you are reading a text file…

Answer (score 0):

After some lengthy research I found that it has nothing to do with parentheses. There is just a problem with that particular file. I have no clue why the search won't find it, but it does not.